# Ocelot Configuration is restoring after restart

Tags: asp.net-core, ocelot

I am trying to implement the Ocelot gateway, and I am using [admin](https://ocelot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/features/administration.html) APIs for updating the configuration on runtime.

So the issue is when I am updating the configuration it is updating the file in bin folder which is expected behaviour, but when I restart my service the configuration is restoring itself.

I tried various things like using consul but the same thing happening there as well.

I am using Ocelot 16.0.1 on .net core 3.1.

[Here](https://github.com/manishtiwari25/ocelot-test) is my git repo.

I have also raised an [issue](https://github.com/ThreeMammals/Ocelot/issues/1276) in ocelot repo.